# How do I implement a combinational circuit that finds which input has more ones?

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

I have 2 16-bit inputs: A[15, 0] and B[15: 0]. There are also two outputs: OUT[15: 0] and Z[1: 0]. The way it works is if # of bits that are 1 in A is greater than or equal to the # of bits that are 1 in B then OUT=A and Z=1, else OUT=B and Z=0.

As an example, if A[15:0]=0010001000100010, B[15:0]=1010101010101010 then B has more 1s and thus OUT=1010101010101010 and Z=0

I'm really new to this and want to implement it with only NOT, NAND gates, Multiplexer, Adder, and Comparator. But I don't know where to start or how to begin. Could anyone help me out or tell me which steps to take? Should I draw out a truth table?

Comment: Does the problem change for 951 bits, 3, 2 or even one? Start with the lowest number of bits the problem looks the same.

Comment: Um - why is Z introduced as a two-bit signal?

Comment: For homework questions we expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work, and then ask a specific question. If you really, truly, don't know where to start then you should talk to your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

Start with *the simplest thing that could possibly work* (XP).

It is OK to select A if
• A = B
• A = 1111111111111111
• B = 0
• A contains at most one 0s (an *or* of 16 15-input *and*s) and B != 1111111111111111
• A contains at most two 0s (an *or* of 16*15 14-input *and*s - dang, this is getting out of hand, ending with 16!/8! 8-input gates - times 2: some billion gates. And doesn't get that much better using complements)
(Trying to make a *unary-to-binary encoder/combinatorial binary counter* along these lines gets worse.)

Looks like one needs to exploit *all bits of any given input being equivalent*.

Hint: All three inputs of a full adder are equivalent.

> The outputs of a full adder are the binary count of 1s at the inputs.

I failed to find a lucid diagram for a "single significance compressor tree" as well as creating one.
[14/15:4 combinatorial counter as falstad.com/circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsUwBY4GYwA4CcYCMB2AJgzwDYsQUQE4I4BTAWl1wChctSRVCIfvUXfrkKEcIXN0ip2nSiW6FKc4aPGTU01gBlKuLhCT6QzAxJAAzAIYAbAM71q4HZSQZwr96Y%20Tr9xwhgslyESIbGqHBKRlwiYnxSMrpwSEgeKWneEL62Dk5BySLpRVnmfnmBLm4QhgqlOf75LqgYaXytJsbZlrkBzrqRSnxRnWYNFf2KNVOjPj2NlRwhoYogoXxKceqJLnD4Zntc9fMTQUvy2aSGcvrZat2aMgDu1PsgcocSxM7nhHCxVzWRAkgK2Dy0L2q7y4GS%207iCL0G0LWGHcInhwThq1wqWx93Mj1YkLcyJ4dwxLzgRRUI3Rk1EbTWK1KEHKfQKa3%20Hj%20Ry6ZV6TV0xHhKK8fPG7KJei4HyKdLOWAQMVWSH4wlQqCKhN0HCGEiwShZJ0lOsBlwgRrZTQ4SuMt0owlBGq1Wht%20s2gN4aKdmqUhMRvGRUPlUoZQZJIZePOR0cjIIgcjDId%20wOFovTYIJrsVa0w6bDadwzr9ENeyzSqr9HSCAA9qKgKLgMKhqLSMFw0ita5Q9hJm5R8Nl25Q1m1WHXNWkm37CPg%200rRxJx2sNfPR7FUSOVmxIQowy00kiEQIQlykWHj4J3NHUteu6GufvkJyDFKr9wRuhD9W38%20ke%20D2cSkijDMJ2jHKMVgLMIXyAoElGjNML2XUJ3E1SRCFIDQcS3Ttlx4ChNRbVAkD9YxOynUNgXPaif1wEYb0TLlYQgJQaCo6I92BJA5GPdYPwQmCeNfKNmNxaN-hqN9BG4DpAKPKpSG-CsFEA6YrUqIA)

(If `Adder` means *k-bit full adder* instead: you can use it as \$\lceil(k-1)/2\rceil\$ independent full adders.)

---

There is an entirely different approach to this:
Build an *n* input unary-to-binary encoder from a *binary sorter*: a circuit moving all 1s to one "end", 0s to the other. You can compare these unary numbers easily, or convert to 1-hot and from there to binary:
*n*+1 *x AND NOT y* gates to get the boundary between 0s and 1s encoded "one hot" followed by a [(simple) encoder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encoder_(digital)).
For 16 bits this takes 4 8-input gates and 137 2-input gates using a "60 arrow" (see below) 10 level sorter.

The circuit to sort two (1-bit) inputs is simple enough:
an OR gate to the 1s end and an AND gate to the 0s end - I'll call it *arrow*.
One very regular construction to sort more than two values/signals/bit is an [odd-even transposition network](https://www.inf.hs-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/networks/oetsen.htm), for 16 inputs it needs 120 arrows/240 2-input gates, and 16 levels/stages.
The fastest/least deep "16-sorter" is 9 levels, the smallest known as of 2023/05 is 60 arrows.
A CIRCUIT**LAB** finger exercise that proved tedious
(The left sorter showing the better half of gates can easily be inverting):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIbIQu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

There are loads of papers on *population count / popcount*, most "scholarly".

Comment: I guess *lookup table* doesn't conform *only NOT, NAND gates, Multiplexer, Adder, and Comparator* - *unless* using 4 abusively large 65536:1 multiplexers is fair game.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your hint? I think this is the way I should be going, but I am not sure how I would set this up.

Comment: One can, of course, recreate the "2-input adder tree" of a decent software popcount in hardware, and get an inferior variant of the Wallace tree implementation. Or use 15 "conditional incrementers".

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a *really* easy ways to do that?

Include some analog circuits.

- Buffer both inputs with buffer gates, all powered from the same 5 V supply (this is to ensure that the voltage from each high bit is exactly the same, and the voltage from each high bit is exactly 0 V)
- Connect 16 equal-value, 0.1 % resistors to input A.
- Connect 16 equal-value, 0.1 % resistors to input B.
- Use an analog comparator IC to see which set of resistors has the highers voltage.
- Drive a multiplexer from the output of the comparator, to select either A or B.

Another easy way to do it is in software, in a microprocessor with at least 48 IOs.

Comment: (Not *quite* combinatorial.)

Comment: I am an engineer: I go for the most practical solution and disregard artificially imposed limitations. ;-)